# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ATL9ProPS.def'

Tags: visual-c++

I have a VC++ project. When i compile the project in VS2008 i get the following linker error:

**Error 1 fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ATL9ProPS.def' **

I have been compiling this same code since a year (with minor changes here and there) now but never saw this error. Also, my project does not refer to any file by name 'ATL9ProPS.def. (I guess this file is part of a project that is save to computer during Visual studio installation)

When i searched for this .def file in my machine i found it in the following location
C:\Documents and Settings\Abi\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ATL9Pro.

But how on earth is this file bothering my project. I have no clue how this is linked to my project. Please help me resolve this.

Comment: more information would help. did you make any changes recently? does this happen on a new empty project? does this happen on a new project with the Use ATL Libraries checkbbox checked?

Answer (score 3):

For details

> Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input
>   -> Module Definition File -> Replace this with the right def file.

Answer (score 0):

Try my moving that file to a different location or by renaming the file. Also see if there is any path in the Linker -> Additional include directories refers to My Documents/.../Projects folder.

Answer (score 0):

Anand,
Thanks for the response. Not exactly Linker -> Additional include directories but The Linker->ModuleDefenitionFile option was referring to the file name ''ATL9ProPS.def'. I just replaced this with the right def file and it worked. Thanks